# Automated meetings schedule planner

Tags: javascript, logic, schedule

I work in an event organizing company, our main business is organizing “speed dating” meetings between buyers (retailers and distributors) and manufacturers of food and beverages. We have people that create a schedule for events and I would like to somehow automate this process.

I would ask for help with logic for a web app that would schedule the meetings.

- There are 10 different companies on each side.
- The meetings should be only if one side chose a company from the other side.
- Each meeting is 15 minutes.
- The whole event should we 2-2,5 hours long.

Any suggestions on how to create a great schedule automatically?

P.S. I am sorry if my question is not clear, this is my first Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a JavaScript solution, but this can be solved with mathematical optimization tools.

Let's start with some data:

```
----     11 SET b  buyers

buyer1 ,    buyer2 ,    buyer3 ,    buyer4 ,    buyer5 ,    buyer6 ,    buyer7 ,    buyer8 ,    buyer9 ,    buyer10


----     11 SET s  sellers

seller1 ,    seller2 ,    seller3 ,    seller4 ,    seller5 ,    seller6 ,    seller7 ,    seller8 ,    seller9 
seller10


----     11 SET r  rounds

round1,    round2,    round3,    round4,    round5,    round6,    round7,    round8


----     11 PARAMETER wantMeeting  a meeting has been requested

            seller1     seller2     seller3     seller4     seller5     seller6     seller7     seller8     seller9

buyer1            1                                                                                               1
buyer2                                                            1                       1
buyer3                                    1           1
buyer4            1                       1
buyer5                        1                       1                       1
buyer6                                                            1           1                                   1
buyer7            1           1                                   1           1
buyer8                                    1                                                           1
buyer9                        1                                   1           1
buyer10                                                                                   1                       1

      +    seller10

buyer8            1
```

Introduce binary variables:

```
  x(b,s,r) = 1 if buyer b meets seller s in round r
             0 otherwise
```

We only consider the cases where `wantMeeting=1`. Implicitly, when `wantMeeting=0`, we assume `x(b,s,r)=0`.

Constraints:

1. Meeting is requested:

   ```
   sum(r, x(b,s,r)) = 1  for all b,s with wantMeeting(b,s)=1
   ```
2. Buyer can only have one meeting per round

   ```
   sum(s|wantMeeting(b,s)=1, x(b,s,r)) <= 1  for all b,r
   ```
3. Seller can only have one meeting per round

   ```
   sum(b|wantMeeting(b,s)=1, x(b,s,r)) <= 1  for all s,r
   ```

Here | is the mathematic notation for "such that".

I have also added some constraints, and an objective to minimize the number of rounds needed. The resulting **Mixed Integer Programming model** gives as result:

```
----     42 VARIABLE x.L  meetings

                      round1      round2      round3      round4

buyer1 .seller1            1
buyer1 .seller9                                                1
buyer2 .seller5            1
buyer2 .seller7                                    1
buyer3 .seller3                                    1
buyer3 .seller4            1
buyer4 .seller1                                    1
buyer4 .seller3            1
buyer5 .seller2            1
buyer5 .seller4                                    1
buyer5 .seller6                        1
buyer6 .seller5                                                1
buyer6 .seller6                                    1
buyer6 .seller9            1
buyer7 .seller1                                                1
buyer7 .seller2                        1
buyer7 .seller5                                    1
buyer7 .seller6            1
buyer8 .seller3                        1
buyer8 .seller8            1
buyer8 .seller10                                   1
buyer9 .seller2                                    1
buyer9 .seller5                        1
buyer9 .seller6                                                1
buyer10.seller7            1
buyer10.seller9                                    1


----     42 VARIABLE round.L  round is used

round1 1,    round2 1,    round3 1,    round4 1


----     42 VARIABLE numRounds.L           =            4  number of rounds needed
```

I did not have a capacity per round (say n tables are available). This is not very difficult to add. More details are [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2020/08/speed-dating.html).

For some more examples of these type of models see:

1. [Scheduling Business Dinners](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/10/scheduling-business-dinners.html)
2. [Speed Dating Scheduling](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/04/speed-dating-scheduling.html)

I probably would solve this on a server, but if you insist on a JavaScript solution, there is a JavaScript port of the GLPK Mixed Integer Programming Solver ([link](https://github.com/jvail/glpk.js/)). You may also look into Constraint Programming Solvers (there are a few available in JavaScript).

Comment: I will try to make some research on the examples you have mentioned, thank you!